# Thread safe detachement of bidirectional link

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I have two objects, A and B, with a pointer to each other.
The object A may be deleted by one thread, and the object B by another thread.
When the object A or B is deleted the remote pointer should be set to NULL (clear the bidirectional link). How do I implement this in a tread safe way ?

While simple to describe, I don't find it easy to implement.
The naive idea is to protect each pointer with a mutex. But to avoid deadlocks the two mutex must be locked in the same order. This would require that one object locks the remote mutex first. But this implies using the pointer in an unprotected way to access the remote lock.

The only solution I found so far is to use one shared mutex referenced by the two objects through a smart pointer. When both objects are destroyed the mutex is destroyed. The single mutex protects access to the bidirectional link. So only one thread at a time can modify the bidirectional link and clear it.

Is there a better method ?

**Edit: Details on the use case**

Data structure:

```
 ______          _____           _____          ______
|      | 1   N  |     |  1   1  |     |  N   1 |      |
|  A'  | -----> |  A  | <-----> |  B  | <----- |  B'  |
|______|        |_____|         |_____|        |______|

Thread_A                                         thread_B
```

A' is fully controlled by Thread_A, and B' by Thread_B. B' and Thread_B is inside a library I have no way to change. But B is constructed with a factory method I provide to the library. So I have full control on the implementation of B.

Thread_B can delete B at any time. I thus have no control on the lifetime of B. Thread_A will close the library before deleting A'. This implies that Thread_B deletes all B and B' objects before Thread_A deletes A'. At regular interval Thread_A scans the list of A and erase A with a NULL pointer to B.

While running, data has to be transferred in this way A' -> A -> B -> B'. Thread_A is storing the data in a queue and thread_B is pulling the data out of the queue. I decided to put the queue inside B, because Thread_A storing the data in the queue is a non blocking operation. If the queue is full data is discarded. When Thread_B tries to pull data from the queue it may stumble on an empty queue. The library implementor requires that Thread_B waits at most 1sec and return.

So I need a protection to secure clearing and testing the bidirectional link status, and to block deletion of B while Thread_A is storing its data in the queue in B.

Comment: I think `weak_ptr` would be a solution as it is

Comment: @Slava, very much doubt so.

Comment: Who owns those objects beside themselves?

Comment: By ownership I suppose you mean responsible of its deletion. One object under control of one thread owns object A and another object under control of the other thread owns B. So you have A' -> A <-> B <- B'. The bidirectional link with cardinality 1x1 between A and B is there because both threads can delete A or B at any time. I need to set the pointers between A and B to NULL to reflect the existence status of the remote (budy) object.

Comment: This sort of desing is not supportable. You have a true circular dependency here, and it is not resolvable. weak_ptr suggested above can not really resolve it. I suggest you rework your design and get rid of circular dependency, which is never a thing to desire.

Comment: @SergeyA That's easy to say and not really helpful. There are many examples in practice where circular dependencies **do** exist. Two subsequent nodes of a linked list is just the most basic example...

Comment: @TheOperator, I am not sure what list are you referreing to. Usually in list implementations nodes do not OWN each other - and by just pointing to each other you do not create a circular dependency.

Comment: @SergeyA I would follow your advice, but I currently don't see how. Weak pointer could be the solution. I didn't investigate it. Maybe you can help. Object B' is fully owned by a library I have no control on. The library code is run by a thread. I do have control on B since I provide a factory function to the library to create B. So I could change the pointer to A into a weak pointer.

Comment: @chmike I have 2 questions (to see what solutions are workable). First question, how critical is it that one object is warned of the deletion of its buddy right when it happens (is a delay allowed, can you use lazy-check)? Second question: can the object to be destroyed first try and announce its destruction to its buddy?

Comment: @chmike, weak pointers will not help you. Weak pointers provide a mean to obtain a shared_ptr to the object, and guarantee that all shared_ptrs obtained from the same weak_ptr will share the same control block. They do not resolve circular dependency. Without shared_ptr existing somewhere, weak_ptr on their own do not manage the object lifetime.

Comment: @DanielStrul It is not critical at all that the other object is notified. The requirements are (1) that the thread running A'  (ThA) can detect that the link from A to B is NULL, (2) that the thread running B' (ThB) can detect that the link from B to A is NULL, (3) that ThB can execute a method from A and that A can't be deleted by ThA during that call (I didn't specified that in the question, sorry).

Comment: @SergeyA The pointer from A to B could be a smart_ptr and the pointer from B to A a weak_ptr. Though this would not solve the third (3) requirement.

Comment: The weak_ptr solution discussed above is a good solution for lazy-verification: the pointer-to-buddy is not updated when the buddy dies but only when the pointer must be used. If the object has managed to make a smart pointer, the object can't die, so it's safe. The main issue is that buddy's destruction can be delayed for as long as the smart-pointer exists.

Comment: @DanielStrul I just understood that I can't use weak_ptr because the library doesn't manage B through smart_ptr. B' to B is a raw pointer and ThB calls delete B !  Also don't need that the lifetime of A and B are coupled. I want it decoupled and its the reason I created a class A and B. Thinking again over it I noticed that there is an asymmetry. A is never deleted before its B buddy. So I can store the mutex in A and that's it. Thread_A and Thread_B can lock on it and secure link testing and modification, call the data queuing method in B by Thread_A  and deletion.

Answer (score 1):

After this very helpful discussion through comments with @Slava, @SergeyA and @DanielStrul forcing me to refine my problem analysis and description, I finally found the solution.

Object A will always be deleted after B. So I can store a mutex in A so that  Thread_A and Thread_B can safely synchronize on it.

I can't use a weak_ptr because the lifetime of B is not controlled with a smart_ptr. B' holds a raw pointer to B and Thread_B calls `delete B`. With the mutex the bidirectional link can be implemented with raw pointers.

Answer (score 0):

First the obligatory warning:

As covered in the comments, there is probably a cleaner way to solve whatever problem you are solving by more clearly separating concerns of lifetime and access.

However, if you're determined to do it this way, the answer is `std::lock(...)`

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock